# c# mvc 5 call json web service and save on database

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Greetings i want to call a web api that returns a json string from From Controller and i want to map it on a class so i can save the data on the database.But i dont understand how to map each data on the json with the class.
I only get the message that is succeed. 
my code is:

```
public ActionResult API()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = client.DownloadString("https://www.example.com/api/all-users?name=user%20&pass=password");
    wclients wclients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<wclients>(text);

    if (wclients.message == "success")
    {
        ViewBag.name = ("name = " + wclients.name);
    }

    return View();
}
```

my view is this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.name) {
<tr>
    <td>
       @item
    </td>


</tr>
```

}

The Response from web api is:

```
{"status":true,"message":"success","data":[{"name":"test test","email":"senthil@nscript.in","phone":"1234567890","affiliated_id":null,"account":{"real":[{"login":"1001175","pass":"4pJccK8AUWw8"},{"login":"3001180","pass":"4AeCqasw7jX2"},{"login":"3001182","pass":"fS2tf6Gsej7C"}]
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I am trying to get the value name so i have a list of names on the view, but what i get on wclients.name its null

Comment: share your `js` code.

Comment: I am not using any js, im trying to pass data through ViewBag.

Comment: share your view code then

Comment: What is the response text that comes back from the web api and what is the class definition for `wclients`? knowing the class structure and the json result from the Web Api will make this a lot easier to diagnose

Comment: Can you please show `wclients`. What is it?

Comment: @TejinderSingh: Why you need js or view code, it doesn't matter with the question!

Comment: why are you using `ViewBag.name = ("name = " + wclients.name);` instead you can try `ViewBag.name =wclients.name;`

Comment: both ways im getting a null there, the only data that i got different the null is the message that its saying succeed

Comment: How does your wclients class look like ?

Comment: try using `ViewBag.name =wclients.data` and iterate through the data and get the name. or you can iterate in your action and get the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code:

```
public ActionResult API()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = client.DownloadString("https://www.example.com/api/all-users?
    name=user%20&pass=password");
    var wclients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);

        if (wclients.message == "success")
        {
            var data = wclients.data;
        }
      return View();
}
```

Comment: wclients.data its not on my class property, and i dont see how with a property data i can get the list of users.

Comment: wclients contains the response you are getting from an api , right?

Comment: wclients its the class that i am using to map the properties together.

Comment: response you are getting from an api contains the `data` property, you can 't get the name without using the data. you can use `var wclients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<wclients>(text);` to access the data.

Comment: @EniSpetsi, i have edited my code changed `text` to `text.data`

Comment: i add the property data and now im getting this error: Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'data', line 1, position 43.

Comment: kindly check my updated code and remove the data from your class

Comment: from were you are getting text.data? because the var text its call the url and with (text.data) its showing error

Comment: this is the response sent by your api, it contains the property named data

Comment: im getting this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i try that to add the property in the class data but if i do it i will get the Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'data', line 1, position 43

Comment: don't add any property in class. just keep the class as it is and try without adding data in class. I have declared `var` type object. it will handle

Comment: i am getting this:
Error CS1061 'wclients' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'wclients' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: could you please share the api link you are using, so that i can use it at my end?

Comment: sorry its not possible because the api its live and got data, but do you use skype?

Comment: i just add you.

Answer (score 0):

`wclients.name` will never contain anything because there is not a property called "name" at the top level of the JSON object structure.

To access the `name` property you would need to enumerate through the `data` array (which should exist as a property on the `wclients` class) and get the name from there.

**Update**

As per the example below:

```
public class wclients
{
    public bool status { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Account> data { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult API()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = client.DownloadString("https://www.example.com/api/all-users?name=user%20&pass=password");
    wclients clients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<wclients>(text);

    if (wclients.message == "success")
    {
        ViewBag.name = clients.data;
    }

    return View();
}
```

and in the view

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.name)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.name
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Sorry i did not understood that please can you share a example?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON must map directly to your C# class.

For example, if the JSON has the following:

```
"name":"test test",
"email":"senthil@nscript.in"
```

Then your class (eg Person.cs) must have the same properties:

```
public class Person{
    public string name {get;set}
    public string email {get;set}
}
```

Then you would do:

```
Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

In your example, you probably need `wclients.data`

```
if (wclients.message == "success")
{
    ViewBag.name = ("name = " + wclients.data.name);
}
```

Finally, the name `wclients` suggests there are multiple... in which case:

```
var names = new List<string>();
foreach(var client in wclients){
    if (client.message == "success")
    {
        names.Add("name = " + client.data.name);
    }
}
```